# Discord.js splitting embed description content

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to split the content of the description of this embed

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
module.exports = {
    name: 'reviews',
    description: 'views your recently customers feedbacks',
    employeeOnly: 'true',
    execute(message, args, client, prefix, db) {
        let reviews = db.fetch(`${message.author.id}.reviews`)
        if(reviews === undefined) reviews = "You don't have any customer feedbacks!"
        if(reviews === null) reviews = "You don't have any customer feedbacks!"
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`Stars - Feedback - Customer`)
        .setAuthor(`Your customers' reviews`)
        .setDescription(reviews)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setColor('YELLOW')
        .setFooter(message.member.user.tag, message.author.avatarURL());
        message.channel.send(embed)
    }
}
```

the "reviews" content usually exceeds the 2048 characters limit Is there a possible way to make the bot make another embed **if** the "reviews" for example exceeds 10 lines I have figured a way to make a reaction menu but struggling at this

Comment: this might be a very crude work around but maybe try to convert the reviews into an array and then split that array into multiple arrays using the 2048 character limit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex to split the description into blocks
`<string>.match(/[^]{2048}/g)`
This will split the strings in parts of max 2048 characters
Then, you could map the array to send embeds for each.